# I need help finding a page

Tags: templates

Alright, I will start by saying that I'm very new to this and will not be using the most technical terminology....

I am helping with a project that someone else left. She created a web page, and I'm trying to edit a few things.

There is one page full of links that redirects to other parts of the website. 
I can edit the redirected pages, but cannot find a way to edit the linking page.

It's frustrating because the linking page is named the same as the page it's redirected to. It's like they should all be in the same template folder, but they're not.

Do you guys have any ideas on how to fix this???

Comment: We really need some more information to help you. Is it ExpressionEngine and can you figure out what version (likely either 2.x or 3.x)? Can you tell us what you've done to try and find the page full of links? It's possible the page full of links is actually a `Channel Entry` in a `Channel` and not actually a template.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to turn on template debugging. That will tell you which template is shown. From there on you can investigate further